# Bootstrap row full height and dynamic wrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

In Bootstrap 4, I want the equal number of split (.col) elements to move to the next line after any number columns. For this, bootstrap wants us to use the (.w-100) class.

This works successfully, but this invisible div prevents the elements from spreading properly as if they take up space on the vertical axis.

You can see it in the example below.

```css
.wrapper
{
  background: lightgray;
  height: 100vh;
}

.col
{
  background: green;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white;
}

.w-100
{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="row" style="height: 100%">

    <div class="col">
    </div>

    <div class="col">
    </div>

    <div class="col">
    </div>
    
    <div class="w-100">
    </div>

    <div class="col">
    </div>

    <div class="col">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

The area shown here with the red background is actually a divider and should not appear physically, so that the green elements on two separate lines spread in a volume equal to 2.

> The problem here is that I can put the divider (.w-100) element after
>   any number of items (.col). it needs to be dynamic.
>
> That's why I'm following this path. Otherwise, if there was a certain
>   number (.col-0 ... 12) I would be able to solve it with its property.

Is there a solution for this, So ignoring that red element in flex propagation?

Of course I tried to set the height of the divider element to 0 here. But even if it does not have its own height, the elements are not divided into 2 equally. Example below.

```css
.wrapper
{
  background: lightgray;
  height: 100vh;
}

.col
{
  background: green;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white;
}

.w-100
{
  background: red;
  height: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="row" style="height: 100%">

    <div class="col">
    </div>

    <div class="col">
    </div>

    <div class="col">
    </div>
    
    <div class="w-100">
    </div>

    <div class="col">
    </div>

    <div class="col">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Do you think this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check this example?

Try to checkout the documentation:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/

```css
.wrapper
{
  background: lightgray;
  height: 100vh;
}

.col
{
  background: green;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="w-100 h-100">
    <div class="row h-50">
     <div class="col">
      1 of 3 columns
     </div>
     <div class="col">
      2 of 3 columns
     </div>
     <div class="col">
      3 of 3 columns
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row  h-50">
     <div class="col">
      1 of 2 columns
     </div>
     <div class="col">
      2 of 2 columns
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but this uses two separate "rows" there. So that's okay. But I need a single `.row` solution.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you say but if check the docs you can see exactly this same situation.

[image]